# Windows Phone - Phone Number Verification

Tags: windows-phone-7, phone-number, windows-live

Is there a way on the Windows Phone to access the users mobile number? Is it possible to gain this information by asking permission or possible having the user sign in via a Windows Live Account to gain the information? I wanted to see if there is a solution other than using Twilio in order to verify a phone number via text message. I'm working specifically on Mango now but would be interested if this would be possible in Apollo as well.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not supported.
To gain this information you will need to ask the user to manually for their phone number. This is to stop their phone number being retrieved by any app which requests it, which could then lead to spam/selling of the phone number (to name a few scenarios)

Considering that this is a security limitation (not a hardware/software limitation), I doubt very much that this security conscious decision will be revoked for Apollo (Windows Phone 8) and access to the phone number will be granted to any app that wants it.

Comment: I think it might be possible if you do get the user to give access via a windows live account - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826526

Comment: Very true, however this can return multiple phone numbers and if the user uses more than one device with the same "Windows Live Account" then there's no guaratee that the number stored in "Mobile" will be the correct one. You would have to display the numbers found and let the user choose the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve contacts with mango.

See : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286414%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Regards.